# How to obtain the maximum value present in a DIV element using CSS selectors?

Tags: html, css

I have a there DIV elements which are housed in another DIV element this form is repeated. ex:
"""

```
<div>
     <div><p>10</p></div>
     <div><p>0.1</p></div>
   </div>
   <div>
     <div><p>2</p></div>
     <div><p>0.2</p></div>
   </div>
```

"""
using a CSS selector I want to select the highest value inside the DIV element and display it
ex: :div not(:first-child) {display: none};
this will display only the first DIV element, I would like to know if it is possible to get the MAX value using such selectors

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: there is no such css selector.

Comment: This sounds like a job for JavaScript! Trying to get an answer based on data, rendered or not is something you'd want javascript to do for you. CSS isn't built for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

There are no CSS selectors that match on the text content of an element (content selectors were deprecated). See [Selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#selectors) for a useful list of available selector patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by sorting the data for each bin and using a css selector to display on only the last child

> div:not(:last-child) {display:none;}